# Can Traefik ForwardAuth authenticate multiple APIs with different URL path?

Tags: traefik, traefik-authentication

I'm new to Traefik.

I just implemented Traefik `ForwardAuth` with my simple auth server.
It seems that Traefik `ForwardAuth` can only manage the service, but can't manage APIs in service.

To give an example:

There's a service SVC with 3 APIs that are: `testAPI_1`, `testAPI_2`, `testAPI_3`.
Traefik `ForwardAuth` can only control who can visit service SVC, but can't control who should visit `testAPI_1` and who shouldn't visit `testAPI_2`.
Can Traefik manage API's authorization/authentication?

Here's my service's setting in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
  whoami:
    # A container that exposes an API to show its IP address
    image: containous/whoami
    networks:
      - my-net
    labels:
      # set middleware
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-auth.forwardauth.address=http://auth-server/whoami"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-auth.forwardauth.trustForwardHeader=true"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-auth.forwardauth.authResponseHeaders=X-Client-ID"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.middlewares=test-auth@docker"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Path(`/whoami`)"
```

Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated!